# not able to push the data in to the list

Tags: angularjs

I have one list which contains list of objects so, now i want to add one more object to the each list in the main list
I am using `AngularJS`

here is the code which i tried

```
$scope.mediaList = [];

$scope.getTheProfile = function(data){
        for(var i in data)
        {
            ProfileService.getByHandle(data[i].handle,function(profiledata)
                {
                    $scope.mediaList[i].displayName = profiledata.name.displayName
                },
                function(data , status){
                    console.log("In Error");
                    if(status == '400'){
                        $scope.errors.push(data["ERROR"])
                    }
                },
                function(data , status){
                    console.log("In forbidden")
                })
        }
        alert($scope.mediaList[0].displayName)
    }
```

so i am trying to add displayName to that list
now the problem is i am not able to get the value in that alert
if that alert is inside `ProfileService.getByHandle` function then i am getting the value

this is the function `getByHandle`

```
this.getByHandle = function(handle, successCB, errorCB, forbiddenCB) {
        console.log("In Profile Service for fetching the profile by handle: "+handle);

        HttpCommunicationUtil.doGet(apiConstants["profile"]["getByHandle"]+"/"+handle, successCB, errorCB, forbiddenCB);
    };
```

Comment: You are passing 3 args to getByHandle, two of which are functions. Could not get why that is needed. Can you post the code for getByHandle method.

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari see the changes now

Comment: Are you getting `undefined` in alert?

Comment: Well, I see you have 3 callbacks. from `getByHandle` you simply passed the callbacks to `doGet`. But where exactly are these callbacks executed?

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari Dont worry about backend code(execution) data is coming onlything is not able to add to the list

Comment: I may be wrong in getting you but the way you have written the code and the way you want to execute ` $scope.mediaList[i].displayName = profiledata.name.displayName` do not work. You are trying to execute something while passing it itself. Probably you can try telling more about your use case for someone to help

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `getByHandle`, it seems you are making *asynchronous* HTTP request using `HttpCommunicationUtil.doGet`.

What happens is this: `for` loop will make the `HTTP` calls and trigger this alert `alert($scope.mediaList[0].displayName)` without waiting for the response of `getByHandle`, as it's an asynchronous request.

Therefore, when you try to `alert` there will be an empty array `[]` value for `$scope.mediaList` due to line#1. So `$scope.mediaList[0].displayName` will produce error saying unable to get displayName of undefined.

You can return [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) in `ProfileService.getByHandle`and when it's resolved use `.then` to update your variable.

If you can post code for `HttpCommunicationUtil.doGet` it'll be more useful.

**EDIT**:
Without `HttpCommunicationUtil.doGet`, I'll give you an idea of how to do it in a generic way.

Service:

```
this.getByHandle : function(params) {
    return $http.get('/api/endpoint');
}
```

Controller:

```
ProfileService.getByHandle(params).then(function(data){
    //use data to push response in $scope.mediaList[i]
});
```

Comment: hey i am new to this can u help me where i should add that promises

Comment: $http itself is a promise..so you can better return $http promise itself. No need for extra $q